# How to find the static text i.e label based on the tag value in swift UITesting?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I tested  the  assertions of static text based on its identifier and label text value.

I want to test this same thing based on the tag value which is assigned to the label.

I tried this code for the testing the static text based on the  label text , value , identifier.

Please help me out.
I'm confused here.

```
        //Based on value coming from backend
        XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["1000"].exists)

        //Based on label text  from Interface builder 
        XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["myLabel"].exists)

        //Based on identifier 
        XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["id1"].exists) 


        //this "Label" have the tag value 1 , So how can I check label based tag
        XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["1"].exists) //Here test fails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the label based on the `tag` only in view controllers as shown,

`let label:UILabel = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel`

It's not working in UI testing , there are only two ways,  i.e accessibility identifier and label text value.